# How to separate data in a v-for with Vue.js 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuedraggable

With Vue.js 3 and the draggable package I'm creating a list of grid elements which I want to separate with Category dividers.

---

**Headline 1**

---

---- Grid Elements with Category "headline1"

---

**Headline 2**

---

---- Grid Elements with Category "headline".

**What's the problem?**

My current way is working, but I think it needs a lot of improvement. Here I share which way I go currently:

```
<template>
  <div class="element-container">
    <h2>Headline 1</h2>
    <draggable 
      v-model="getElementsForCurrentRole" 
      group="headline1" 
      @end="save" 
      item-key="name">
      <template #item="{element}">
        <n-card v-if="element.category == 'headline1'" class="brf-element" :class="'brf-' + element.name" :title="formatElementName(element.name)" size="small" header-style="{titleFontSizeSmall: 8px}" hoverable>
          <n-switch v-model:value="element.active" @update:value="save(element)" size="small" />
        </n-card>
      </template>
    </draggable>

    <h2>Headline 2</h2>
    <draggable 
      v-model="getElementsForCurrentRole" 
      group="headline2" 
      @end="save" 
      item-key="name">
      <template #item="{element}">
        <n-card v-if="element.category == 'headline2'" class="brf-element" :class="'brf-' + element.name" :title="formatElementName(element.name)" size="small" header-style="{titleFontSizeSmall: 8px}" hoverable>
          <n-switch v-model:value="element.active" @update:value="save(element)" size="small" />
        </n-card>
      </template>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>
```

As you can see, I create multiple for loops iterating the same array. I separate the elements just by showing only specific elements with the needed category (`v-if="element.category == 'something'`).

But: When I have 50 categories, I need 50 for loops. And I loop trough the exact same array each time. I think there is a better solution. What would be the best practice here?

**Edit**

Tried the tipps from Lawrence Cherone's comment. It works and its much less code. Great. But: what does not work (and also did not work before I guess) is the indexing. When I drag elements from the second category, the elements from the first changes their position. What's the issue here?

```
<div v-for="cat of elementCategories" :key="cat">
  <h4>{{cat}}</h4>
  <draggable 
    v-model="getElementsForCurrentRole" 
    group="{{cat}}" 
    @end="save" 
    item-key="name">
    <template #item="{element}">
      <n-card v-if="element.category == cat" class="brf-element" :class="'brf-' + element.name" :title="formatElementName(element.name)" size="small" header-style="{titleFontSizeSmall: 8px}" hoverable>
        <n-switch v-model:value="element.active" @update:value="save(element)" size="small" />
      </n-card>
    </template>
  </draggable>
</div>
```

Comment: loop over your `categories = [{'key': 'headline1', 'title': 'Headline 1'}, ...]` then use `key` for group and the check, though id go down the route of making a computed value which puts the items for each group along side key and title, then simply loop over, doing it in the render loop is inefficient, additionally your going to have empty divs

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence Cherone, I've edited my post with some additional informations after trying your solution! :) Do you have any idea here? I think that every group starts with index 0..but in the end of the day, I need a continuous array..

Comment: use `:group="cat"`

Comment: Same result... I've edited my comment above with some thoughts about it. What do you think?